# How to exit from zsh commit message when accidentally write a semicolon and press enter

Tags: version-control, zsh, commit

Usually, when one writes a commit message it does it like this:

```
git commit -m 'this is my message'
```

But by mistake instead of closing the quotes you press `;` and `enter` so it happens this:

```
git commit -m 'this is my message;
quote>
```

How can it be exited from here? Is there a way to remove the last action?

Comment: This depends on your shell, not Git, but hitting Control-C should cancel the current command without executing it.

Comment: `quote>` is a `zsh` prompt indicating that the shell is still waiting for input, inside a quoted value.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

You will be able to redo your command afterwards by hitting <kbd>↑</kbd>.